# Highchart can't find table created from loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I have a partial view where I use a model to create a table. The problem is that I think my highchart can't find the table. Because when I use an example table  outside the loop the chart is rendered.

My HTML and JS:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
for (var j = 0; j < Model.Calculation.Count; j++)
{
    var rowID = 1;
    var cellID = 1;


    <div class="compareTableId-@j">
    <legend>
        <h4 id="excelFileName">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Calculation[j][0].CalculationName)</h4>
    </legend>
<table cellspacing="0" id="detailTable-@j" class="compareTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Row
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date
                    </th>
                    @if (Model.InvoiceAmount && Model.InterestAmount)
                    {
                            <th>
                                Invoice amount
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Interest amount
                            </th>
                    }  
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Calculation[j].Count; k++)
            {
                <tr id="@rowID">
                    <td align="center">
                        @rowID
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Calculation[j][k].PeriodStartDate)
                        - @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Calculation[j][k].PeriodEndDate)
                    </td>
                    @if (Model.InvoiceAmount && Model.InterestAmount)
                    {
                            <td align="center" id="A-@cellID">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Calculation[j][k].InvoiceAmount)
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" id="B-@cellID">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Calculation[j][k].InterestAmount)
                            </td>
                    }
                </tr>
                    rowID++;
                    cellID++;
            }
            <tr id="@rowID">
                <td align="center">
                    Total:
                </td>
                <td align="center">

                </td>
                @if (Model.InvoiceAmount && Model.InterestAmount)
                {
                        <td align="center">
                        @Model.Calculation[j].Sum(item => item.InvoiceAmount).ToString("0.00")
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                        @Model.Calculation[j].Sum(item => item.InterestAmount).ToString("0.00")
                        </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    }
}
<div id="chartContainer"></div>



<script>
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chartContainer',
            type: 'line',

        },
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('detailTable-0')
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Graph of your calculation'
        },

        xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        id: 'x-axis',
        title: {
            text: 'Payment Periods'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        }

    });
});
```

This code above is not working. I have tried calling the JS on buttonclick as well but it's still not working.

But the exact same code is working when I just put in an example table outside the loop the chart is rendered.

Example table:

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Jane</th>
        <th>John</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Apples</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pears</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Plums</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Bananas</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Oranges</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So when I change getElementById from detailTable-0 to dataTable it works.

Does anyone see the problem with my highchart code when I try to render a chart from the first table created inside the loop? (or the table). I have checked table ID and it is the same (detailTable-0)

Comment: is partial view loaded via ajax?

Comment: No it's not. I'm using a Html.BeginForm to render a new view

Comment: But even when I tried render the chart on buttonclick it didn't work, then detailTable-0 is already filled with data

Comment: As I see your id of table is different than you get.

Comment: After your buttonclick, when you inspected the javascript console for errors, what did it say?

Comment: Also, your example table is from the highcharts docs, it's not what your real table looks like at all.  What happens if you hardcode your real table?  What does your real table look like after it is rendered?  Update your question with that.  That's where the error lies...